# Every time I power on my toshipa satilite a105-s2236 laptop (ubuntu 14.04.3) it says "ACPI PCC probe failed" what should I do?

Tags: 14.04, acpi

I do not understand computer language. Every time I power on my system it says "[     1.493615] ACPI PCC probe failed." Sometimes the type gets smaller and a second line appears and then it goes to the log-in screen, but this does not happen often, when at the log-in screen, after about a second, the screen freezes and the pointer wont even move. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If your system finally boots and works OK, do nothing. If the system doesn't boot, freezes all the time, and it annoys you

- back up your files
- if your laptop won't boot, unplug it, take your hard drive to any HDD enclosure and copy important files to another computer
- download and install a different OS from the USB stick (you may want to Google how to create a bootable USB stick)
- choose "erase everything" option during the installation, and don't keep an old OS
- see what happens

"ACPI PCC probe failed" message is typical for Ubuntu 14.04 when you install it to a pretty old machine. Choose a system designed for older machines and less resource hungry. Likely you will need Linux Mint Mate 32-bit, because your laptop seems pretty old. If it's the one that initially came with Vista, it's a really old one. It may be just incompatible with some latest Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Thank you I will try Linux Mint Mate 32-bit. Yes it is the vista laptop. I originally tried the 32-bit Ubuntu from a dvd. Do you think a dvd would work also? (instead of a USB flash drive)

Comment: If your laptop has an optical drive and it works (reads and writes CDs and DVDs) you can burn iso file to DVD and install Ubuntu (or Mint) from DVD. Don't burn it to DVD-RW, burn it to DVD-R and you should be OK.